# HADOOP_COMMON_HOME and HADOOP_HDFS_HOME variables are unset in Map reduce jobs which are invoked from client side

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I'm noticing that HADOOP_COMMON_HOME and HADOOP_HDFS_HOME env variables are unset when investigating logs to query for java.classpath in map/reduce job logs.

Default yarn.application.classpath is
$HADOOP_CONF_DIR, $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*, $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*, $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*, $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*, $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*, $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*

From the java.classpath variable mentioned in each mapper (or) reducer logs, I see that HADOOP_COMMON_HOME and HADOOP_HDFS_HOME is completely unset causing "/share/hadoop/common/lib/*" "/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*" etc., to be appended.

The map reduce jobs are submitted from client side to the hdfs cluster.

The M/R jobs are failing with the below error:

```
    INFO: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster failed 
    in state INITED; cause: 
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException:     
    java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: 
    java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs
    at 
 org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$2.call(MRAppMaster.java:518)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$2.call(MRAppMaster.java:498)
    at ...
```

Appreciate any suggestions as to why these are unset and suggestions to resolve this?